# Feeding data frame columns to xyplot panel functions

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I am using xyplot on a data frame and want to feed a panel function with data that is not the (x,y, ...) arguments, but some additional column of the data frame (say k in the example below):

```
library(lattice)

mydata <- data.frame(xxx = 1:20,
                     yyy = rbinom(20,20,.5),
                     uuu = gl(2,10),
                     k = rnorm(20))

xyplot( formula = yyy ~ xxx | uuu, data = mydata,
        panel = function(x,y,k, ...){
                n <- x * k
                panel.xyplot(n,y,...)
                })
```

I understand that this will not work, because R does not feed this k column to the panel function. Is there a simple way to do so?

(I'm not trying to just multiply x by k in my actual panel function. I'm calling another function that requires k...)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what the useful (but somewhat obscure) `subscripts` argument is for. From the description of the "panel" argument in `?xyplot`:

> [...] the panel function can
>    have 'subscripts' as a formal argument.  In either case, the
>    'subscripts' argument passed to the panel function are the
>     indices of the 'x' and 'y' data for that panel in the
>     original 'data', BEFORE taking into account the effect of the
>     'subset' argument.

In other words, a formal argument named "subscripts" will contain the row numbers in your `data` argument that correspond to the data being plotted in the current panel -- just what you need to pick out the desired subset of the `k`-values.

In your case, do:

```
xyplot(yyy ~ xxx | uuu, data = mydata, K = mydata$k, pch=16, 
       panel = function(x,y,K, ..., subscripts){
                   n <- x * K[subscripts]
                   panel.xyplot(n,y,...)
               })
```

(Note that there was one odd complication in this application. An argument to `xyplot()` named `k` will get interpreted as `key`, due to partial matching of arguments. To prevent that, I named the relevant argument `K` so that it would be passed, intact, to the panel function.)